# How to delete only a parent entity in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, relationship, orphan

I have a Person object. Person has a manager property which is again of type Person.

```
@OneToOne(optional = true, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
private Person manager;
```

Say John is the manager and Bob is the employee. When I am trying to delete John, it fails since Bob becomes orphan (without Manager). That should be allowed in my use case. But marking this relationship "optional" doesn't help. And Cascade doesn't seem to have any significance here.

I presume this is possible with JPA. Any help?

```
@Entity
public class Person {

@Id
private String id;

private String name;

private Integer age;

private Address address;

@JoinColumn(name = "manager_id", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true)
@OneToOne(optional = true, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
private Person manager;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "manager", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
public Collection<Person> reportees;
```

Comment: Is `manager_id` column in database configured as not null?

Comment: The "id" field in Person should be the manger id and there is no explicit field otherwise.

Comment: With these mappings, `manager_id` has to exist in the database. It holds the id of a person that is a manager to the "current" person.

Comment: How to mark it nullable (I thought optional will do it)? I am actually using the JPA beans to create the DB schema and not otherwise.

Comment: `optional` should do it, I was just wandering if it is actually not null in the database. Also, a full exception would help, and the code that causes the exception.

Comment: Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: DELETE on table 'PERSON' caused a violation of foreign key constraint 'PERSON_MANAGER_ID'
 for key (john).  The statement has been rolled back.
Error Code: 20000
Call: DELETE FROM PERSON WHERE (ID = ?)
 bind => [john]
Query: DeleteObjectQuery(com.ca.ucf.oapi.test.jpa.Person@643eae)
 at

Comment: You forgot to add the `mappedBy="manager"`

Comment: Wouldn't that become property manager mappedby manager?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your question. What do you mean?

Comment: Also please note, that you can and should mark questions as accepted, if you get at least a correct answer (accepting an answer is not the same as upvoting it).

Comment: @Andrei what I meant was that when I added mappedBy="manager" to the manager property the JPA reported error and did not boot up.

Comment: @Anil What was the error, when you added `mappedBy="manager"` ?

Comment: @AndreiI here you go :) thanks a lot for looking into this.. 
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7213] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Circular mappedBy references have been specified (Class: [class com.ca.ucf.oapi.test.jpa.Person], attribute: [manager] and Class: [class com.ca.ucf.oapi.test.jpa.Person], attribute: [manager]. This is not valid, only one side can be the owner of the relationship. Therefore, specify a mappedBy value only on the non-owning side of the relationship.

Comment: btw, did you mean that I add the other side of the relationship (reportees) and set mappedBy="manager" on that property. Actually I even tried that but still I was facing problems while deleting a Person who is mapped as a "manager" to another Person.

Comment: Please note that you put `mappedBy="manager"` on the `private Person manager;` and not on the `private Person employee;`. As I describe in my answer, it is the `employee` property that should be annotated.

Comment: Just did.... still it doesn't let me delete :(

com.ca.ucf.oapi.exception.ConflictException: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: DELETE on table 'PERSON' caused a violation of foreign key constraint 'PERSON_MANAGER_ID' for key (john).  The statement has been rolled back.
Error Code: 20000
Call: DELETE FROM PERSON WHERE (ID = ?)
 bind => [john]

Comment: code updated in the query.. pls check. Thanks @AndreiI

Answer (score 1):

You should set `null` as Bob's manager, before trying to delete John. Also, @Andrei is right, you should map this as bidirectional `@ManyToOne` relation (although your code will work if you know all the persons that have John as their manager).

Answer (score 0):

1. I doubt the relationship is `@OneToOne`, as there are many employees that have the same manager.
2. If you insist that it is `@OneToOne`, then make the relationship bidirectional, by adding the property in the `Person` Java class:

   ```
   @OneToOne(mappedBy="manager", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }) 
   private Person employee;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the parent entity before deleting children. Not the ideal solution but works for me.

I also tried the bidirectional relationship (by adding @ManyToOne reportees property of type Person) and marked the relationship "optional" using @JoinColumn also marked nullable=true. But nothing worked.